# DropdownList gets no value from Viewbag bind

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have dropdownlists populated from my controller and passed in the view through viewbags. The binding seems okay until I submit the form and gets null value. But when I put the codes in the view itself, it works. Am I missing a cast?

a snippet of my dropdownlist for "Year":

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Year, new SelectList(ViewBag.Year, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Whereas the ViewBag.Year data is from my controller that has the ff codes:\

```
List<SelectListItem> year = new List<SelectListItem>();

                for (var i = 1990; i <= DateTime.Now.Year; i++)
            {
                year.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = i.ToString(),
                    Value = i.ToString(),
                    Selected = false
                });
            }

ViewBag.Year = year;
```

the error I get:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a case when user submitting the form and validation mechanism fails (returning same view), `ViewBag.Year` has `null` value when passed to `DropDownListFor` (since it's not repopulated after POST request) and throws `ArgumentNullException`.

To solve this issue, simply repopulate `ViewBag.Year` when returning the same view in POST method, by replicating how to populate `ViewBag.Year` in GET method like this example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitForm(FormModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // other stuff
    }

    List<SelectListItem> year = new List<SelectListItem>();

    for (var i = 1990; i <= DateTime.Now.Year; i++)
    {
        year.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = i.ToString(),
            Value = i.ToString(),
            Selected = false
        });
    }

    ViewBag.Year = year; // this line repopulates ViewBag when submit failed

    return View(model);
}
```

Similar issues:

[Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items (DrodownList)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357321/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-items-drodownlist)

[Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items (in Dropdown List) ASP.NET MVC5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921483/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-items-in-dropdown-list-asp-net-mvc5)

Comment: oh I have to rewrite the code. hmm seems inefficient. I guess I'll try to separate the population in an independent method that returns a list then call it whenever I need it.

Comment: It is true that I prefer creating an independent method which populates `ViewBag.Year` and call the method on both GET & POST method there. I had explained what's wrong: the `ViewBag` is not repopulated while POST method returns same view.

Comment: I can't set the default value in this case of populating the list programatically